# The GameObject transform automatically sets to (0, 0, 0) when i apply Perlin Noise

Tags: perlin-noise, heightmap

I am learning how to use the Perlin Noise with some Documentation. So far i mostly understood quite a lot.

Here i post the codes in order:

**The Noise Code**

```
public static class Noise {

public static float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, float scale)
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[mapWidth, mapHeight]; //We create new 2D array

        if (scale <= 0)//If input scale is 0 we will have a 0 div!!
        {
            scale = 1f; 

        }

        //We loop through the noise map
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
            {
                //Now at which point we are sampling our height values
                float SampleX = (float)x/scale; //For non integer values we divide by scale
                float SampleY = (float)y/scale;

                float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise(SampleX, SampleY);
                noiseMap[x, y] = perlinValue; //We assign the Perlin noise value to the 2D thing
            }
        }
        return noiseMap; //We return the noiseMap we generated
    } 
}
```

**The Map Generator**

```
public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public int mapWidth;
    public int mapHeight;
    public float noiseScale;

    public bool autoUpdate;

    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        //We will fetch the noiseMap from the Noise class
        float[,] noiseMap = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap(mapWidth, mapHeight, noiseScale);


        MapDisplay display = FindObjectOfType<MapDisplay>();
        display.DrawNoiseMap(noiseMap);


    }

}
```

**Map Display**

```
public class MapDisplay : MonoBehaviour {

    public Renderer textureRender;

    public void DrawNoiseMap(float[,] noiseMap)
    {
        int width = noiseMap.GetLength(0);
        int height = noiseMap.GetLength(1);

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);

        Color[] colourMap = new Color[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                colourMap[y * width + x] = Color.Lerp(Color.black, Color.white, noiseMap[x, y]);
            }
        }
        texture.SetPixels(colourMap);
        texture.Apply();

        textureRender.sharedMaterial.mainTexture = texture;
        textureRender.transform.localScale = new Vector3();
    }
}
```

**EditorControls Code**

```
//This class controls the editor so instead of MB we use Editor
[CustomEditor (typeof(MapGenerator))]
//We have to say it is custom and the "typeof" of the class
//the custom editor is, in that case. MapGenerator

public class MapGeneratorEditor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        MapGenerator mapGen = (MapGenerator)target;//The object being inspected.

        //If we changed anything in the Editor, it will autoupdate.

        if (DrawDefaultInspector())
        {
            if (mapGen.autoUpdate)
            {
                mapGen.GenerateMap();
            }
        }




        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate"))
        {
            mapGen.GenerateMap();
        }

    }

}
```

This last piece of code makes a button inside the Inspector so when i press it. The whole thing runs and gives me the Perlin Noise Map displayed on a plane.

**Plane Configuration (Inspector)**
[image]

**QUESTION**

The problem i have right now is that when i press the Generate Button (see below):

The Planes Scale goes from (1, 1, 1) to (0, 0, 0) and i do not know why it does that. The only way to get back my Perlin Noise displayed on that Plane is if i manually setup the plane a Scale.

What i am missing here?

Thanks for answer.

[image]

Comment: You told it to:  `textureRender.transform.localScale = new Vector3();` sets scale to (0,0,0).  You probably meant to set scale to (1,1,1)

Comment: @Wyck that's an answer I'd upvote if you'd care to write it. :)

Comment: Wish i could upvote that comment.

Comment: @WhiteGlove once a question has an answer, we should not edit it to make it a different question that isn't addressed by that answer.  Question posts are free, so just post a new question if you want to ask something new, even if it's related to the same project or feature.

Comment: Oh sorry, i just though that the previous question was too stupid (i missed something in the code) so then i switch it to something more complex. The edit took place before that new answer appeared i gave thumbs up (not showing because i do not have the required level in this community)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told it to set the scale to zero when you wrote `textureRender.transform.localScale = new Vector3();`  That's because a new Vector3 is initialized to (0,0,0).  Scale is multiplied, so "no change in scale" is represented by the value of 1 (not zero), so you probably meant to set the scale to (1,1,1), so you'll need to write `new Vector3(1,1,1)`.

Alternatively, the default localScale is (1,1,1) so you could just avoid assigning it a new value altogether and keep its original value of (1,1,1).

Comment: Yeah i already solved it but did not updated the code.